# automatic template argument deduction not working

Tags: c++, templates

Why do I get:

```
missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
```

when using:

```
sort(index_mu.begin(), index_mu.end(), index_cmp(mu_pt_corrected));
```

where `index_mu` is `std::vector<int>` and `mu_pt_corrected` is `std::vector<float>`

```
template<class T> struct index_cmp {
    index_cmp(const T arr) : arr(arr) {}
    bool operator()(const size_t a, const size_t b) const
    { return arr[a] > arr[b]; }
    const T arr;
};
```

isn't the compiler able to undestant the type of `T`? Why?

Comment: Not for `index_cmp`, no.

Comment: Template parameter deduction works only for function templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template argument deduction only applies to functions.  In
general, the compiler won't have the necessary information to
deduce the arguments for a class.  For this reason, it's common
in such cases to add a function along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
index_cmp<T>
indexCmp( T const& arr )
{
    return index_cmp<T>( arr );
}
```

You can then call:

```
sort( index_mu.begin(), index_mu.end(), indexCmp( mu_pt_corrected ) );
```

The compiler will deduce the type of the function, which in turn
defines the type.

Comment: thank you, by the way why "the compiler won't have the necessary information to deduce the arguments for a class" ?

Comment: Because the instantiation of a class template normally doesn't occur in the context of an expression, and when it does, the compiler has to know its type before trying to find a corresponding constructor.  In the very special case where the class has a single constructor, which takes a single argument of the same type as the template, the compiler could work it out, but the case probably seemed to special to the committee to be worth introducing a lot of extra rules.